# Canonical(s) for Python infinitely-nested/recursive defaultdict questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are many Python questions on how to do an infinitely-nested/recursive defaultdict, which one(s) should be canonical?

1. [Nested insertion/creation of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880124/nested-insertion-creation-of-dictionary)
2. [Multi-level defaultdict with variable depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth/8702435)
3. [Is there a standard class for an infinitely nested defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178249/is-there-a-standard-class-for-an-infinitely-nested-defaultdict) [**No, but it's typically a one-liner**]
4. **Recommended** [Nested defaultdict of defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)
5. ...please add to this list...

Known duplicates:

1. [Python3.6 4-level dictionaries giving KeyError [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938150/python3-6-4-level-dictionaries-giving-keyerror)

Related but distinct:

1. [Can't pickle recursive nested defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730315/how-to-convert-dict-into-recursive-defaultdict-and-load-json)
2. [PERL-like autovivification with default value in Python, and returns a default value from non-existing arbitrary nesting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482862/perl-like-autovivification-with-default-value-in-python-and-returns-a-default-v)
3. [Set Python dict items recursively, when given a compound key 'foo.bar.baz'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729220/set-python-dict-items-recursively-when-given-a-key-foo-bar-baz)
4. [How to convert dict into recursive defaultdict and load JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730315/how-to-convert-dict-into-recursive-defaultdict-and-load-json)

and even:

- [lxml FAQ 3.8 "How can I map an XML tree into a dict of dicts?"](https://lxml.de/3.8/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts)

Comment: This might be worth putting onto the related but distinct list: [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) - has a great answer, but not strictly a dup.

Comment: @jpp: Sure, you (and anyone else) have my blessing to edit any bona-fide related-but-distinct into the list, with an URL, also please explain tersely in-line why (the question or its answers) are distinct (in this case: because they're only concerned with (non-infinite) n-level dictionaries, so they don't strictly need defaultdict or recursion, although it would still be a solution, and arguably the 'best' solution, unless performance-critical). Also, distrust old performance numbers from 2013/ Python 2.7.4 or so, hence the recommendation to prefer `setdefault`

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is **[(2) Multi-level defaultdict with variable depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth/8702435)** & **[(4) defaultdict of defaultdict, nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested)** are good canonicals. They have good, highly upvoted answers and have stood the test of time. In addition, many posts have already been marked duplicates of these.

In fact, I believe these 2 questions should be merged. The only "keyword" discrepancy for Google is the former uses "Multi-level" and the latter uses "Nested". I'm confident a question can be phrased which, at least in the body and possibly even in the title, utilizes both these terms.

I generally see reluctance to merge questions, but I think this is a clear case where it *is* warranted, as every answer on both posts is applicable to either question.

The other options you put forward, (1) & (3), don't seem as generalized.

Comment: Thanks. Any opinion which of 2), 4) should be primary? 4) "Nested defaultdict of defaultdict" sounds clearer to me

Comment: @smci, I'd prefer (4) since it gives a working example of a one-level nested `defaultdict` and explicitly asks for extension. While (2) is more a problem statement.